# JavaScript - fetching data from webserver only getting 'redirected' response from cors

Tags: javascript, django

So I managed to make my first API accessible locally.
However when I try to fetch data like I would normally (URL to phpscript to get data from db), I only get a Response telling me that I was successfully redirected. In which way should I change my fetch function to make this work?

script.js

```
async function getTop10() {
    let url = 'http://192.168.2.131:81/stern';
    try {
        let res = await fetch(url);
        console.log(res);
        return await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
getTop10();
```

Response

```
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://192.168.2.131:81/stern/', redirected: true, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://192.168.2.131:81/stern/"
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

Sample dataset from the url

```
[
    [
        "Nach",
        20
    ],
    [
        "In",
        16
    ],
    [
        "Sie",
        15
    ],
    [
        "Die",
        14
    ],
    [
        "So",
        10
    ],
    [
        "Putin",
        10
    ],
    [
        "Das",
        9
    ],
    [
        "Ukraine",
        9
    ],
    [
        "Deutschland",
        9
    ],
    [
        "Der",
        8
    ]
]
```

Comment: You only logged the response. You should also log the JSON you returned. Otherwise, it should work (although it does not log the JSON as you never tell it to log the result returned from the function).

Answer (score 0):

```
**you are console logging res. try console logging res.json()**
const getTop10 = async () => {
      let url = 'http://192.168.2.131:81/stern';
      try {
            const res = await fetch(URL);
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
      }
}
getTop10();
```

Comment: It is generally frowned upon to simply include code in your answer. Please make sure to include an explanation of your in addition. That way, the asker gets a general overview of why your answer works and can possibly use that to help them later on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).